# accordion en tabla

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla en mysql y php y quisiera que al momento de darle click en una fila me mostrara con accodion el valor para "comentariosfinales", pero al momento de darle click a una fila me muestra para todos mis filas, quisiera que al darle click me mostrara una por una, este es mi codigo:

```
  <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo" class="clickable">
                  <td>' . ($key + 1) . ' </td>
                  <td>' . $row["NombreEtrenado"] . ' ' . $row["ApellidosEntrenado"] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $row["telefono"] . '</td>
                  <td>' . $row["finicio"] . ' <--> ' . $row["ffin"] . '</td>
                
                  <td> 
                  <select class="example-css" name="rating">
                  <option value="' . $row["evaluacionFinal"] . '">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
                  </td>
                  <td> 
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info js-verevidDetalles" identrenadodet="' . $row["id_entrenado"] . '"  ><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                  </button>                     
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success js-verevidentrenado" identrenado="' . $row["id_entrenado"] . '"  ><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                  </button>                      
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning js-verevaluacioneditid"  identrenado="' . $row["id_entrenado"] . '"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                  </td>    
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td class="collapse demo">' . $row["comentariosFinales"] . '
                  </td>
                  </tr>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque con `data-target=".demo"` te estás refiriendo a todos los elementos que poseen esa `class`. Para hacer lo que quieres tienes **hacer que el target sea único**.

por ejemplo usar el id:

```
<td class="collapse demo" id="demo_' . $key . '">' . $row["comentariosFinales"] . ' </td>
```

y luego referenciándolo:

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo_' . $key . '" class="clickable">
```

De esa manera cada `data-target` se refiere a un solo elemento y no a todos los que comparten la `class`